# people nearby contacts appears twice in empathy list, how to correct this?

Tags: empathy, avahi

Using empathy and "people nearby" in Ubuntu 12.04, my contacts appears twice.

This bothers me, how can I correct this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to `avahi` which will probe ipv6 and ipv4 network as you can see with:

```
avahi-browse -t _presence._tcp
```

Each user presence is broadcasted in ipv6 and ipv4.

Thus, if you don't need ipv6, you can set `ipv6` to `no` in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`. Don't forget to restart `avahi` with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon restart
```

In my experience, it can take several minutes for empathy to remove all spurious duplicate contacts.